# Identify SMD component on USB hub

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

[image]I have a USB 3.0 hub, Amazon Basics, and I need to identify this SMD component.
I take a photo, it is mark B135H with some special characters like you see on image.
Please, could you tell me which component is? I need to buy it and change.

[image]

Comment: if you do not know what it is, then how do you know that it requires replacement?

Comment: I can't find anything with the marking, but the Q1 designator next to it suggests it's a transistor of some kind. Make a photo that shows more of the surrounding circuit and we can tell you more.

Comment: Because i have another equal to this, and it is explode. I want to fix the other that is not working.

Comment: The pin next to the letter H (B135H) is directly connected to the 5v input power pin.

Comment: @Chipyto Thanks to the new picture I was able to find the MOSFET. Patricks answer is wrong. It's not a NPN transistor.

Comment: @Chipyto yup, nanash1 is right (or at least my answer is definitely wrong), the 5 V connection on pin 2 made that clear.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Based on additional Info my answer is most likely wrong, since according to Chipyto pin 2 is at 5 V, which would not make sense with this part.

I'd say it is one of these two:
[image]

Both are marked with B13, "5H" might be a manufacturing date. It is also a transistor, which would fit the silkscreen mark ("Q" is often used for transistors).
The only difference between the two parts listed is the package, I believe what you need is the SOT-23 one but im not sure on that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Sinopower SM2413PSAN](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1138025/SINOPWER/SM2413PSAN.html) P-Channel MOSFET.

[image]

I can't find a picture of the SM2413PSAN, but if we look at other MOSFETs from Sinopower, like the APM2300CAC-TRG, we can see that the marking style matches.

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_Sinopower-Semicon-APM2300CAC-TRG_C207577.html))

The pinout also matches with the one in the picture. OP said in the comments that pin 2 is directly connect to the 5V source.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, i will try it to fix it with your details.

Comment: thanks for correcting me @nanash1, out of curiosity, how did you find that part? I used a couple different searchengines and all came up empty (besides the one i mistakenly posted)

Comment: @PatrickFiedler These search engines are a decent starting point, but I always try to find pictures that confirm the part is the right one. In this case, the pictures of the NEC (now Renesas) part didn't match with marking shown in the picture, so I was sceptical. After OP added context, it was clear that it was likely a PNP BJT or p-channel MOSFET, so I searched for pictures of those transistors, mainly on LCSC, and looked if there was a manufacturer with the same marking style. That's how I found Sinopower. I used the way they describe the markings in the datasheet to find the right part.

Comment: @nanash1 thank you for those insights! Im adding LCSC to my resources, that site seems really helpful for this sort of task (and the photos are incredibly useful).